# Zend Framework 2 Module Redirect The page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: redirect, zend-framework2

I've got some problem with proper redirect in Zend Framework 2 in Module.php.
Iceweasel browser shows this information:
"The page isn't redirecting properly".

My code is simple, but seems it generate some problem:

```
$eventManager->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function ($e) {
    $auth = new AuthenticationService();                                        
    if (!$auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $url = $e->getRouter()->assemble(array(), array('name' => 'login'));
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
        $response->setStatusCode(302);
        $response->sendHeaders();
        return $response;
    }
});
```

Anyone could you give me some zf2 tip why Iceweasel react with above message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going into an infinite redirect loop. Since all of the Module classes get instantiated on every request, this event binding gets called every time. You need to add something like

```
$route = $e->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
if(!$auth->hasIdentity() && $route !== 'login') {
...
}
```

That way it doesn't try to redirect again when you reach the login page.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add a route condition.
Thank you for a quick answer.